# Linear Regression Analysis using SPSS (I think)

Tags: regression, time-series, spss

I am trying to conduct a study into whether or not female board presence affects firm performance. My background is accountancy and business NOT maths or statistics and so I don't really understand SPSS or regression analysis. However, I have been told that this is what i must do.

I have obtained data on 68 companies, and am planning to use the % of Women on the Board as an independent variable and Net Income as a dependent variable. I want to compare the effect of % of women on Net Income over 68 companies over 5 years.

Does anyone know how to do this in SPSS? And whether this is the right kind of analysis to be conducting based on the research parameters?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Adam. Do you have a statistical concepts / understanding question here? This question looks half like 'how do I do ______ in SPSS' (which would be off-topic for CV, see our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq)), & half 'how do regression & time-series work', which really requires you to take a couple semesters of statistics, not a couple paragraph long CV answer (much as I do like them). Can you edit your Q to clarify the specific statistical question that you have?

Comment: As with @gung I am uncomfortable with the way you have conceptualized this.  As others have said you will need to take several statistics courses to be able to do a competent job with this type of analysis and its interpretation.  And the fact that you or your boss automatically assume that LINEAR regression is the way to go is quite telling.

Comment: What about the effect of net income on the % of women?  Or the effect of something else on both of them? To make any kind of case for a causal effect in an observational study needs a lot more than a 'significant' regression coefficient.

Comment: BTW did you consider saying 'No' when you were told? It's what I'd say to my boss if he asked me to do the year-end accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site.

Given the data you have and the questions you raise, I think you need some sort of multi-level model (aka mixed model and various other terms).

This is because your data are over 5 years. Such data will violate one of the assumptions of regression: That the errors are independent. A company's income and % of women on the board in (say) 2010 is not independent of those numbers in 2009.

If you are new to statistics, such a model may be hard for you to run and understand; you might want to consider consulting an expert.

Comment: Ok thank you for your quick response. What if i don't have access to an expert, is there anything that you think i might be able to do myself? or any kind of guide that i can consult that you are aware of?

Comment: (+1 to Peter)  OTOH, if you feel comfortable averaging each company's 5 years' worth of income figures to create a new dependent variable, then your task becomes much simpler and might entail garden-variety linear regression.  How to conduct that in a particular program is a question for another venue, though....But have you considered whether you've accounted for all relevant variables?  For instance, maybe your analysis would be sounder if you controlled for company size at the start of the 5 years.

Comment: thanks but the whole purpose of my research is to determine whether female representation improves performance at which point i feel i need to chart what is happening over a number of years

Comment: @rolando2 's suggestion is a good one. Or, if you prefer, you can just use one year's data. Or, you could do each year separately and compare the results.

Comment: Well, in that case, you could create a new variable "change in performance" (e.g. year 5 - year 1) and compare that to % of women in the first year. This is not ideal, but it is simpler.

Comment: would it be statistically sound to do each year individually and then regress them or would there then not be enough data points to do that (my understanding is that you need around 40 impressions to successfully run regression analysis)?

Answer (score 2):

You should really look at existing research. I found these that might be helpful:

- Rose, Caspar. "Does female board representation influence firm performance? The Danish evidence." Corporate Governance: An International Review 15.2 (2007): 404-413.
- Ahern, Kenneth R., and Amy K. Dittmar. "The changing of the boards: The impact on firm valuation of mandated female board representation." The Quarterly Journal of Economics 127.1 (2012): 137-197.
- Campbell, Kevin, and Antonio Minguez Vera. "Female board appointments and firm valuation: short and long-term effects." Journal of Management and Governance 14.1 (2010): 37-59.

In short, a linear regression from gender ratio to income is not the best measurement to make. You should probably cede to existing research.